# Why is my visual basic button greyed out?

Tags: vb.net, button

Everytime I create a visual basic button and place it on form it is greyed out. I have no idea and I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I've googled everywhere and I can't find a solution to why my button is greyed out. The same thing occurs when I create a label too, I can't click it.

Comment: Please post a screenshot.

Comment: The common reason it is grayed out is because it is disabled. Is your buttons placed in any containers inside your form?

Answer (score 2):

In button's properties 'disabled' option must be turned on.

Another way to enable it is in your code

```
button1.enabled=true
```